# Resolving and understanding external symbol errors in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

Very new to C++ and the VS IDE, and I'm trying to start working with Dear imGUI and openGL with a hello world function. I've added resources with lib and dll files before for c++ (for openGL), but not something like imGUI which only has .h and .cpp files - feels like I'm struggling to understand how to inform VS of where those are and how they link up.

Here's an example of an error I saw when building:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _glfwGetWindowSize referenced in function "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame(void)" (?ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame@@YAXXZ) imGUITrial1 ..\Coding\imGUITrial1\imgui_impl_glfw.obj   1

So I opened up imgui_impl_glfw and found the function, and it appears to reference a function declared in glfw3.h...but that function looks like just a declaration, with no definition. I had previously added each folder with these files in it to the project additional directories, so I went ahead and added glfw3.h as a resource to my sources folder in the solution as well. That didn't change anything, so now I'm not sure how to find where the function is actually defined, or if the issue is that I need to somehow tell VS that this file exists in a another nested properties window?

Maybe it will help to have a screenshot of the solution. These are largely files copied from the github that I haven't changed (which I chose from looking through the backend examples), so I don't think I broke anything in the files themselves.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSWk2.png)

Comment: Locate and add the gflw library to you linker's list of additiona libraries.  It's either glfw3dll.lib or glfw3.lib, depending if you want to use the dynamic or static gflw library.

Comment: This was exactly it. Spot on for also helping me understand the difference between the lib and dll. Note for future references that I also immediately ran into errors based on the Visual studio version (see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5150eeec-4427-440f-ab19-aecb26113d31/updated-to-vs-2015-and-now-get-unresolved-external-errors?forum=vcgeneral )